# Swift message alert exit button doesn't work

Tags: swift, firebase, alert

I am creating an application in which a user, based on the permissions he has, can access the various views.

I use this method to constantly check user permissions:

```
func checkPermission() {
    let docRef = self.DatabaseFirestore.collection("Admins").document(phoneNumber)
    docRef.getDocument{(document, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            
            return
        }
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            self.controlloAdmin = true
            
            guard let data = document.data() else {
              print("Document data was empty.")
              return
            }
            self.permission = data["Permessi"] as? [Bool] ?? []
        } else  {
            self.controlloAdmin = false
            self.isRegistred = false
            self.access = false
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is the most correct function I could use, but it is one of the few that I have found that works.

This is my view:

```
struct AdministratorPage: View {

@StateObject var administratorManager = AdministratorManager() 

// User variables.
@AppStorage("phoneNumber") var phoneNumber: String = "" // User number.
@AppStorage("Access") var access: Bool = false 

var body: some View {
    
    administratorManager.checkPermission()
    
    return NavigationView {
        HStack {
            VStack {

                Text("Home")
                Text(phoneNumber)
                
                // Button to log out.
                Button("Logout", action: {
                    self.access = false
                })
                
                Button("Alert", action: {
                    administratorManager.message = "Error title!"
                    administratorManager.message = "Error message!"
                    administratorManager.isMessage = true
                        
                }).alert(isPresented: $administratorManager.isMessage) { 
                    Alert(title: Text(administratorManager.title), message: Text(administratorManager.message),
                          dismissButton: .default(Text("Ho capito!"))) 
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I call the "administratorManager.checkPermission()" function and press the "Alert" button the message is displayed, but even if the button is pressed the alert does not disappear. If I don't call this function, everything works.

How can I solve? Can the alert go against firebase? Is there a more suitable method to read only one data?

[photo of the screen when it got locked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YleoZ.jpg)

Comment: Hi @mickele29, I don’t really understand what you try to do and what (and when) it is working and what (when) not. So there is a button, when you click it, it opens an alert and when you press the button on the alert, nothing happens? Or does the alert not even open? It works when you don’t call the checkpermission() function? Best, Sebastian

Comment: Sorry for my poor exposure @SebastianFox . When I press the button the alert opens. When I press the dismiss button the alert does not disappear. This happens, however, when I call functions related to firestore. I used to call up 2 functions that concerned firestore, which I have now synthesized into a single function (code modified above). Through this "improvement" the alert disappears only after the dismiss button is pressed 2/3 times (before it did not disappear despite several taps). I hope I have improved my bad exposure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and I saw the behavior you described.
The reason is the function call directly in the body.

If you want to call a function when when you open a view, use the .onAppear function for that specific view. In your case

```
.onAppear {
    administratorManager.checkPermission()
}
```

The following (worked for me with you code):

```
struct AdministratorPage: View {
    
    @StateObject var administratorManager = AdministratorManager()
    
    // User variables.
    @AppStorage("phoneNumber") var phoneNumber: String = "" // User number.
    @AppStorage("Access") var access: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return NavigationView {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    
                    Text("Home")
                    Text(phoneNumber)
                    
                    // Button to log out.
                    Button("Logout", action: {
                        self.access = false
                    })
                    
                    Button("Alert", action: {
                        administratorManager.message = "Error title!"
                        administratorManager.message = "Error message!"
                        administratorManager.isMessage = true
                        
                    }).alert(isPresented: $administratorManager.isMessage) {
                        Alert(title: Text(administratorManager.title), message: Text(administratorManager.message),
                              dismissButton: .default(Text("Ho capito!")))
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            administratorManager.checkPermission()
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE: add Snapshot listener instead of polling

Your initial approach was doing a kind of polling, it called the function constantly. Please keep in mind, when you do a Firebase request, you will be billed for the documents you get back. If you do the polling, you get the same document multiple times and will be billed for it.

With my above mentioned example in this answer, you just call the function once.
If you now want to get the live updated from Firestore, you can add a snapshot listener. The approach would be:

```
func checkPermission() {
    let docRef = db.collection("Admins").document(phoneNumber).addSnapshotListener() { documentSnapshot, error in //erca nella collezione se c'è il numero.
        guard error == nil else {
            print("ERROR.")
            return
        }
        
        if let document = documentSnapshot {
            self.controlloAdmin = true
            
            guard let data = document.data() else {
                print("Document data was empty.")
                return
            }
            self.permission = data["Permessi"] as? [Bool] ?? []
        } else  {
            self.controlloAdmin = false
            self.isRegistred = false
            self.access = false
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever a value changed on that document in Friestore, it'll be changed on your device as well.

Best, Sebastian

Comment: This solves the alert problem, but creates other problems for me as I constantly need to update the permissions variable. Is there perhaps another method to solve this problem?

Comment: Hey @mickele29. Maybe I misunderstand what you try to achieve. When you used the checkPermission() function as you did it before, it will be called constantly, you are polling for updates on Firestore (that is why the dismiss button didn't work, the system was busy). The approach in my answer calls it just once when you open the view. If you want to get live changes from the database (that is what you did with the polling), add a snapshot listener to your function. I added this alternative approach to my answer, if I misunderstood, please let me know. Best, Sebastian